# How to set the border of a scene to a different color JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a game using JavaFX and I wanted to know if it was possible to set the border of the scene to a different color like black or gray? I happen to be using stack pane as my scene to display the game.

Comment: If you are using SceneBuilder you can change the color there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css.  Create a css file, set the file as the stylesheet for the pane, and add this code to the stylesheet:

```
.root {
    -fx-border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: In most cases this works, but not in all cases. It requires the scene part to be a `Region`, but e.g. `Group` can be used as scene root too. It may also be simpler to use inline style, e.g. if this is the only thing the CSS stylesheet would be used for: `root.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");`